# Separate double number larger than 10 digits in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I have written a code that separate a double number into whole and fraction part, but it gives the correct answer for number upto 10 digits only (decimal part+fraction part), how do i separate double number larger than 10 digits?

```
double num, temp;          
int j=1;          
int whole,frac;          
num= 122.007094;           
temp= num;          
whole=(int)num;         
// FOR THE FRACTION PART     
do{
  j=j*10;      
 }while((temp*j)%10!=0);       
j=j/10;      
frac= (int)(num*j)-(whole*j);       
System.out.println("Double number= "+num);      
System.out.println("Whole part= "+whole+" fraction part= "+frac);
```

Comment: `C` or `Java` choose one ?

Comment: Why you tagged it as C???

Comment: What do you want printed for the "fractional part"? The exact value of num is 122.00709399999999504871084354817867279052734375.

Comment: You do realize that most numbers larger than ten decimal digits don't fit into an int?

Comment: @EJP how do i get the fraction and the digits before decimal part as a whole number then(without decimal point)? like num= 1236758511.98746514, whole=1236758511 and fraction=98746514. If the answer is I can't then its ok but  if you know the answer, please guide and if you don't know, stop criticizing every of my post again and again. You didn't reply my previous post also.

Comment: @kaze You can't even have a double whose value is 1236758511.98746514. The closest double is 1236758511.9874651432037353515625. No int or long can store 9874651432037353515625. You also need to say what you want to have happen when there are leading zeros after the decimal point. There may well be ways of doing what you want, but I can't design one until I know what is is you want, and in particular how you want to deal with the fact that most decimal fractions cannot be exactly represented in double.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use `java.lang.Math.floor(double)` for the integer part, and then subtract that from the original number to get the fractional part.  (If that doesn't do what you want for negative numbers, then use `Math.ceiling(double)` for the integer part when the number is negative.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt at what I **think** you want. I've left the results in String form both to preserve leading zeros in the fraction part, and to avoid overflow. If you want to do arithmetic, rather than display, I recommend converting the String results to BigInteger, which will not overflow.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    double num1 = 122.007094;
    double num2 = 1236758511.98746514;
    testIt(num1);
    testIt(num2);
    testIt(1e7);
    testIt(0.1);
    testIt(0.12345678901234);
  }

  public static void testIt(double in) {
    String[] result = doubleSplit(in);
    System.out.println("num="+in+" whole="+result[0]+" fraction="+result[1]);
  }

  /**
   * Split the decimal representation of a double at where the decimal point 
   * would be. The decimal representation is rounded as for Double.toString().
   * @param in The double whose decimal representation is to be split.
   * @return A two element String[]. The first element is the part
   * before where the decimal point would be. The second element is the part
   * after where the decimal point would be. Each String is non-empty, with 
   * "0" for the second element for whole numbers.
   */
  public static String[] doubleSplit(double in) {
    /* Use BigDecimal to take advantage of its toPlainString. The 
     * initial Double.toString uses its rounding to limit the
     * number of digits in the result.
     */
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(in));
    String [] rawSplit = bd.toPlainString().split("\\.");
    if(rawSplit.length > 1){
      return rawSplit;
    } else {
      return new String[]{rawSplit[0], "0"};
    }
  }
}
```

The output:

```
num=122.007094 whole=122 fraction=007094
num=1.2367585119874651E9 whole=1236758511 fraction=9874651
num=1.0E7 whole=10000000 fraction=0
num=0.1 whole=0 fraction=1
num=0.12345678901234 whole=0 fraction=12345678901234
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. It is working properly upto 18 digits.